# White Raspberries after a frost

Tags: raspberries

My raspberries have turned white.  They were red, but we had a frost and now are white, are they still okay to eat?

Answer (score 2):

They won't poison you, unless the white is actually a mould of some sort and you're sensitive to moulds, but they may not taste great - the cold has probably caused the whitening effect, and will likely have damaged the tissues/cells of the fruits.  If you are going to eat them, do it as soon as possible - they'll start deteriorating rapidly now they're frost damaged. it is a little odd though - I regularly freeze raspberries, and they aren't white once defrosted, but possibly this effect is because the berries are still on the bush and weren't frozen solid.

Comment: and in general, late fall raspberries are not so tasty (not bad taste, just very water like). @bamboo I think the "sunny" raspberries had time to get the color inside the berries. In this case I think the color was still only on the peel. [Not sure, but in grapes it is so].